# Visual Studios Prompts for Vault Repository at Solution Load

Tags: visual-studio-2008, repository, prompt, sourcegear-vault

Whenever I load a specific solution under source control (Vault), Visual Studios (2008) prompts me to choose the repository. This takes the form of Vault's Choose Repository prompt. I have a default repository selected in the Vault GUI but whenever I load a specific solution, it prompts me for the repository. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vault with Visual Studio 2005. Whenever I load a solution up, Vault will also ask me for a default repository, username and password. I'm thinking that this is the way that Vault reconnects it's session back to the repository.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That would seem to be the case, but it has only started recently and only with one specific project. Even then, I'm only prompted to pick the repository not for a username or password.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Could it be that you were using a profile inside of vault that automatically connected to a repository, and that profile is no longer valid which is causing you to have to choose your repository?